# JMS Bridge use case

Tags: jms, integration, messaging

What are the typical use cases for JMS bridges? I.e. when should you typically prefer setting up a JMS bridge vs just using a regular queue with a producer and consumer?

Answer (score 0):

Dont know if this is really relevant. But I had a case where I needed regular data from around 350 servers all running JMS Server and producing indivisual reports. So in order to centralise this process we created a central Server with Oracle integration and created JMS bridges to all 350 servers to fetch data from specific topics and queues. This was a more practical solution rather than creating 350 subscribers.